# Countifs formula to exclude duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates, countif

I am having troubles with a Countifs formula to count the amount of trucks that arrive at a warehouse. The formula is counting correctly but I have run in to a problem were the the total is inflated because some trucks have multiple loads that come through as individual lines so they are counted more than once.

The below formula is what I have the counts the correct amount of lines but I can't figure out how to only count the lines that do not have the same Confirmation Numbers (located in Column A). I have read other posts about a Frequency array but can not get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
=COUNTIFS([@[Customer Name]],"<>Wildfork*",[@Carrier],"<>UPRR      ",[@Finish],"=                ",[@Date],TODAY(),[@[Shift Time]],">="&$EA$2,[@[Shift Time]],"<="&$EB$2,[@[Planned Shift Time]],"=A")
```

Comment: Review [how to count unique items](https://exceltrick.com/how_to/count-unique-values-excel/) and see if that helps.

Comment: [Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)